# Using curl in https

Tags: php, curl

I tried accessing a website using curl and it just output Object moved to here. I used curl_error but doesn't show any errors.

```
$url = "https:somewebsite.com";

$ch = curl_init($url);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // Accepts all CAs
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_error($ch))
{
echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: best way to debug curl is `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`

Comment: check the timeout

Comment: Not sure if typo in code, or typo in question, but your url is malformed.